# Setting value in array inside foreach loop PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, key-value

Hello I am setting a key value pair in an array in a foreach loop

e.g

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
  ["resourceType"]=>
  string(4) "File"
  ["resourceName"]=>
  string(4) "Test"

  [1]=>
  array(1) {
  ["resourceType"]=>
  string(4) "File"
  ["resourceName"]=>
  string(4) "Test"
 }
```

I am doing this via a foreach loop

```
foreach ($output as $data) {



$resourceType = strpos($data, "d");

if ($resourceType) {

    $ftpArray[]['resourceType'] = "Folder";
} else {

    $ftpArray[]['resourceType'] = "File";
}

$resourceName = strrchr($data, " ");

$resourceName = trim($resourceName);

if ($resourceName != ".." && $resourceName != "." && $resourceName != "") {

    $ftpArray[]['resourceName'] = $resourceName;

}

}
```

But the output is this

```
[0]=>
array(1) {
["resourceType"]=>
string(4) "File"
}
[1]=>
array(1) {
["resourceType"]=>
string(4) "Test"
}
[2]=>
array(1) {
["resourceType"]=>
string(4) "File"
}
[3]=>
array(1) {
["resourceName"]=>
string(9) ".htaccess"
}
```

Rather than the example I gave at the start of the question. How can I get the array to fill in key values pairs like the first example.

Answer (score 1):

Make an tmp array

```
foreach ($output as $data) { 
  $a = array();
  if (strpos($data, "d")) { 
    $a['resourceType'] = "Folder"; 
  } else { 
    $a['resourceType'] = "File"; 
  } 
  $resourceName = trim(strrchr($data, " ")); 
  if ($resourceName != ".." && $resourceName != "." && $resourceName != "") { 
    $a['resourceName'] = $resourceName; 
  } 
  $ftpArray[] = $a; 
}
```

Each calling of `$ftpArray[] = 'x'` adds new item to the array. It does not metter if you add there some second dimension key.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a datastructure to a array. This, create the datastructure, do your stuff and add it to the array:

```
foreach ($output as $data) {
  $struct = array('resourceType' = > '', 'resourceName' => '');

  // do stuff, on the struct

  $resourceType = strpos($data, "d");
  if ($resourceType) {
    $struct['resourceType'] = "Folder";
  } else {
    $struct['resourceType'] = "File";
  }

  $resourceName = strrchr($data, " ");
  $resourceName = trim($resourceName);

  if ($resourceName != ".." && $resourceName != "." && $resourceName != "") {
    $struct['resourceName'] = $resourceName;
 }
 $ftpArray[] = $struct;
}
```

Notice that there is a sub tile difference with the previous answer, as the structure is always created.

Answer (score 0):

Each [] operation on array adds a new element to the loop, so you would need to create a temporary value and then add it to the loop:

```
$element = array();
// set the data here
$output_array[] = $element
```

And second thing with that script string positions start with 0, so if you need to know that character was not found when using [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) you should check the return value with === or !== for FALSE.